# White Space to the Right of Website on Mobile Devices

Tags: mobile, removing-whitespace

http://cardiffhosp.rapdevs.co.uk/ has been built around the WooTheme Canvas, which is a responsive design.

I've had to disable the viewport meta tag, because I don't want the layout to be responsive.

It now looks much better on mobile devices, but a white area is appearing to the right hand side. Mostly visible on iPhone/iPad, but zooming out on other devices shows the white space is there.

Adding the following code, solved my problem, but caused the navigation to stop working on iPhones and caused display issues on a Windows 7 phone...

```
html, body {
   overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Has anyone got a better solution for removing the white space?

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding `width:100%` and see if that solves the issue the overflow is causing, IE:

```
html, body {
    overflow-x:hidden;
    width:100%;
   /* You may also want to try adding:*/
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

If that still causes problems then you will need to find the element that is causing the issue.

Couple ways to do this. (Be sure to remove `overflow-x:hidden;` before starting.)

1) Open the inspector, start with the divs or elements that contains other elements. Set those divs to `display:none`. If the excess white space disappears then you can find the offending element and fix its CSS.

If that option is too time consuming or you have trouble doing it, you can try another option:

2) [This site](http://wernull.com/2013/04/debug-ghost-css-elements-causing-unwanted-scrolling/) has some CSS which outlines all of the elements on your site. This can help you find what is causing the overflow. The CSS used on this site is:

```
* {
   background: #000 !important;
   color: #0f0 !important;
   outline: solid #f00 1px !important;
}
```

They also provide a [javascript bookmark](http://javascript:(function()%7Bdocument.body.innerHTML+=%22%3Cstyle%3E*%7Bbackground:%20#000%20!important;color:%20#0f0%20!important;outline:%20solid%20#f00%201px%20!important;%7D%3C/style%3E%22;%7D)();) that helps with this as well.